# Ant inside Robot Framework

Tags: ant, robotframework

Robot framework is generic keywords base testing framework. So can we use Ant task as a keyword in robot?

If yes what are the possible ways?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use "Run And Return Rc And Output" keyword from "OperatingSystem" Library

```
*** test cases ***
Test Ant
  ${RC}    ${Output}    Run And Return Rc And Output    ant -f "antFile name"
```

where you need to set ANT_HOME and also set ANT in path variable
as 
set PATH=%PATH%;%ANT_HOME%/bin

which will then run the ant task defined in ant file.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use directly a Ant Task as a Robot keyword, but you can use [Run Process](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Process.html#Run%20Process) keyword from the [Process Library](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Process.html) to launch the Ant command line you want to run:

```
*** test cases ***
my test
     Run Process  ant command line to launch
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@{Flag}=  Run And Return Rc And Output  run.py
```

should Contain `@{Flag}  Camera Locked`

The result will be saved in `Flag` variable and the next line will search for *Camera Locked Text* in output.

If you simply want to run just use **Run And Return Rc**